# How do I match this brick?

Tags: brick

I am trying to find a good match for some 1930 bricks (North West England).  Any ideals on makes and model of bricks that will match well.

[image: close up]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't. Old bricks are a) likely not being made anymore and b) have weathered. The best bet is to take them to a local brick seller/yard and see how close you can get. If you're replacing a large-ish section, take out more bricks that you need to replace so you can stagger the new with the old to help blend in a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's worked for me in the past (though this was with brick shape rather than style) was to e-mail photos to some reclamation yards.

It might not yield results - after all some yards have 10,000's of bricks on site, but you might get a name for the style of brick or a further contact who might be able to help.

Comment: I did that last night but have not got any results form it yet.

Comment: @Walker, here are a few resources that should prove helpful: [Send us your Brick photo FREE!](http://www.matchingbrick.co.uk/send.html) & [BrickSmith](http://www.bricksmith.co.uk/) & [Ibstock](http://www.ibstock.com/) & [Brick Development Association](http://www.brick.org.uk/)

Answer (score 2):

By getting very creative you may be able to

1. Find a similar brick and try to custom color it to match pretty close.
2. You rebuild with what you have and add some design to it by blending natural stone with it etc...
3. Look for a wall that has the same brick on the property that doesn't need them or isn't seen, (like an outbuilding, covered side entry, porch, or an inside wall, fireplace or chimney) and  use them.

I happen to do masonry restoration and run into the same thing.